# Hyperlink to new page via javascript not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hyperlink

In the gridview, I have a TemplateField containing a hyperlink for each row.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" HorizontalAlign="center"  ForeColor="White" BackColor="Gray" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="gridItem" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink id="hyplnkAuditTrail" runat="server" href="##">Audit Trail</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and the behind code:

```
Protected Sub gvHotelMarkup_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvHotelMarkup.RowDataBound
    Try
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim hlnkAuditTrail As HyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("hyplnkAuditTrail")
            hlnkAuditTrail.Attributes.Add("onclick", "audittrail(" & e.Row.DataItem("HotelId") & "," & ddlGS.SelectedValue & ");")

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        lblErrMessage.Message = ex.Message()
    End Try
End Sub
```

and the javascript link

```
<script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    function audittrail(HotelId,Source)
{   var strUrl = "frmGDSAuditTrail.aspx?HotelId=" + HotelId+"&Provider=" + Source;
    var width = 700;
    var height = 300;
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(width/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(height);
    window.open(strUrl,null,
                            'width='+ width +','+
                            'height='+ height+','+
                            'top=' + top +',' +
                            'left=' + left + ',' +
                            'status=yes,' + 
                            'toolbar=no,' + 
                            'menubar=yes,' + 
                            'location=no,' + 
                            'scrollbars=yes,' + 
                            'resizable=yes'
                            );
}
```

But when the link was clicked, the new page wouldn't show.

I used breakpoints, but the attribute of the hyperlink bounded just fine.

Comment: Why are you showing us server side code and not the code the browser deals with?

Comment: isn't it still a server side problem?

Comment: Only if the problem is (a) the browser opens the URL and gets the wrong response or (b) you know what is wrong with the JavaScript and want help changing the server side code to generate different client side code (in which case you need to show us the actual and desired generated JS!).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I've solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this line:

```
hlnkAuditTrail.Attributes.Add("onclick", "audittrail(" & e.Row.DataItem("HotelId") & "," & ddlGS.SelectedValue & ");")
```

to this:

```
hlnkAuditTrail.Attributes.Add("onclick", "audittrail(" & e.Row.DataItem("HotelId") & ",'" & ddlGS.SelectedValue & "');")
```

worked for me.

You don't need the extra " ' " for HotelId, because it is an integer. But ddlGS.SelectedValue is a string. So you need to wrap it with " ' " .

Comment: I just figured this ' out and wanted to answer this question myself when I saw your answer. And yes, this did the trick. I had missed out the ' in the previous code. I didn't realize this before. Thanks a lot for answering.